# Packaging node.js into a jar with maven, issue with location of node_modules

Tags: java, node.js, maven, npm, jar

I have a maven build the configures a React front end into the java jar file. It worked fine on the mac, but now that I've transferred it to windows, I've run into an issue.

Specifically, the maven build is looking for a file in "app/node/node_modules" when the file is actually in "app/node_modules". Here the error message:

```
 --- frontend:1.13.4:npm (npm run build) @ licensing-app ---
[INFO] Running 'npm run build' in C:\dev\analytics-licensing-app\server\app
[INFO] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
[INFO]     throw err;
[INFO]     ^
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: Cannot find module 'C:\dev\analytics-licensing-app\server\app\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
```

This is the relevant part of pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>app</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>test</arguments>
                            <environmentVariables>
                                <CI>true</CI>
                            </environmentVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

Here is the directory structure the front end:

```
<base-dir>/server/app
```

pom.xml is located in

```
<base-dir>/server
```

This is what's in the "app" directory:

[image]

As you can see, for some reason there is a "node" directory in there, and I'm not sure how it go there and if it's supposed to be there.

I'm also not sure if the build should be there. One of the front end guys was helping me install node on windows, and I think it might have been created by running the "npm run install" manually.

Note that for this, I converted from "yarn" to "npm", because that's they way they do it here.

Also, the contents of config.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/downloadjs": "^1.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-cookie": "3.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "6.5.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
```

What could be maven to look inside the "node" directory for "node_modules"?